# Nullable property raises validation error while it shouldnt

Tags: c#, entity-framework, breeze

Using Entity Framework with Breeze, I have this class Taxi with nullable int TravelID:

```
public class Taxi
{
    // some primary key/Id stuff

    // Then these:
    public int? TravelID { get; set; }
    public virtual Travel Travel { get; set; }
}
```

(simplified of course) Mapping looks like this:

```
public TaxiMap()
{
    this.Property(t => t.TravelID).IsOptional();
}
```

My database tool (HeidiSQL) shows that the property is nullable and the default is also NULL. But when I try to save a Taxi entity I get this validation error:

```
errorMessage: "'TravelID' is required"
```

The TravelID was required before but I changed that like this. This error occurs when the TravelID is null. When it's 0 I get a FK constraint error.

So now my question is, did I forget anything/do something wrong to make the nullable work?

**Added after 1 hour**: I have found a workaround for now but it's really dirty and i'd really prefer not using it. In the front end I set the TravelID to '0' to pass the validation, then in my controller I set the Taxi's TravelID to NULL  before saving.

Comment: As you mention entity framework as tag, did you update the model after making the cjhange that TravelID is now optional instead of mandatory?

Comment: Have you added `TaxMap` to EF configuration object?

Comment: Yes to both Thomas and Jenish.

Comment: @Peter Your update to question **I set the Taxi's TravelID to NULL** does not make any sense since you mentioned in your question `This error occurs when the TravelID is null`...

Comment: @JenishRabadiya the problem is that is does make sense. When the TravelID is null when I try to save the entity in the frontend I get the validation error mentioned above. So to pass the validation I set it to 0 in the frontend, then in the backend change it to null because else the backend throws a Foreign Key contstraint error. (But I totally get your confusion by the way)

Answer (score 0):

The TravelID is not the actual ID of your Taxi class, it is a foreign key to the Travel class. The mapping you're trying to make work here should be in the TravelMapper, as it belongs there.

If you take it to the next step, you can omit all of this and use attributes on your models, such as the autogeneration attribute above the ID property:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

This way you ensure the Travel class must have an ID but in the Taxi class there is nothing that obligates you to specify an object of type Travel.

Comment: Although your observations may be valid, I dont think it really answers my question. I have multiple models which are mapped in the same way (originally not by me but by another intern who worked on this project before me) and they all work without problems. And yes, I'm aware that the TravelID is a foreign key.

Comment: If you are aware TravelID is a foreign key, why are you mapping it as a primary key? If you compare this particular mapper to the others, are they any significant differences such as relationships (one to one, one to many, ...)

Comment: I have a Flight class which looks exactly the same except for some specific properties and that one works without a problem so that confuses me.

Regarding the key, T.Id is the primary key and T.TravelID a foreign one as far as I understand... To avoid possible confusion i'll remove the T.Id part from my question.